# How to annotate a Django queryset with a boolean value for "is older than n days"?

Tags: django, django-orm

Given the toy example of a model:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    published = models.DateTimeField()
```

How might you get a queryset such that you can tell whether the article was published over 2 years ago?

I was thinking something like this, but it didn't pan out:

```py
Article.objects.all().annotate(
    is_relevant=ExpressionWrapper(
        timezone.now() - F("start") > timedelta(days=365 * 2),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

Basically, I want to be able to iterate over the list of articles and access `article.is_relevant` in the template to decide how I might render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work with it the opposite way:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Article.objects.annotate(
    is_relevant=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(published__gte=Now() - timedelta(days=2 * 365)),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

We thus check if it is published *after* two years ago.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!  I'd seen `Now()` around on other examples, but no one explained where it was imported from, so that was nice too.